# Is Jahia 7.3 compatible with AdoptOpenJDK 8?

Tags: adoptopenjdk, jahia

Due to Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap policy update, I would like to know if Jahia 7.3 is compatible with AdoptOpenJDK ?

In Jahia's prerequise and requirement there is "OpenJDK 8", does it mean AdoptOpenJDK included?

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Jahia is tested with RedHat OpenJDK, but AdoptOpenJDK should work just fine, we are actually using it on some of our Jahia installs.

Best regards,